# Не работает с разделенным массивом

Tags: php, массивы, регулярные-выражения

Возник вопрос, почему preg_grep в php не работает с разделенным массив с помощью explode, а только с уже созданным с изначальными значениями?

```
$string = '78:89:13-76:390013:14-79:0:0';

$array = explode('-', $string);

$search = preg_grep('/76:\d:\d/', $array);

print_r($search);
```

Вот такая строка, отказывается работать, а вот такая работает:

```
$array = array('78:89:13', '76:390013:14', '79:0:0');

$search = preg_grep('/76:\d:\d/', $array);

print_r($search);
```

Возникает вопрос, в чем же разница?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не будут работать оба варианта. Почему?
Потому что у вас неправильно составлено регулярное выражение.
Оно ищет такой шаблон:

```
76:1 цифра:1 цифра
```

А в массиве у вас есть только вот такое значение:

```
76:6 цифр:2 цифры
```

И это выражение под шаблон поиска не подходит.
Исправьте регулярку на указанную ниже и все у вас заработает:

```
/76:\d+:\d+/
```

Comment: Спасибо, всегда не понимал эти регулярные выражения.